# How can I reset recurring meeting in vba?

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote vba script to duplication my main calendar to another calendar, including recurring meeting. All is well except when the organizer do out-of-order modifications to the recurring meeting as meeting exceptions.  This triggers error for .GetOccurrence(). The solution I can think of is to reset the recurrence pattern (.Exceptions.Count=0) and redo each and every exceptions again. May I know how can I reset the recurrence pattern so that there is no exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I know how can I reset the recurrence pattern so that there is no exception?

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property for that. You need to re-create an appointment anew and set up a recurrence pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error in the `GetOccurrence()` method, that means you are not passing the right date - you need to trap the exception and use the `RecurrencePattern.Exceptions` collection instead.

If you still want to reset the pattern and using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) is an option for you, it exposes [RDOExceptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOExceptions.htm).`Clear`  method to remove all exceptions from an appointment as well as [RDOExceptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOExceptions.htm).`Restore` to remove a particular exception

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the reply. I re-work my program to avoid the need to reset the recurrence pattern. The key realization for me is the function of `Original Date`. This is the "key" that link my main calendar and my duplicated calendar. I need to loop through all the exception to find the appointment that matched based on original date. With that, I can then use `exception(i).start` as the key to `GetOccurrence()`.